# What do Xavier's seizures do?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In the film [Logan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3315342/), Professor Xavier has several seizures during which the people around him seem greatly affected (Difficulty to move? Slowing of time?).

I don't remember this ever occurring in any other X-Men film, which might be why I had a hard time understanding what was going on, so **what do his seizures really do to his surroundings, both for mutants and non-mutant people?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The seizures mentally paralyse those within range.**

Professor Xavier's ability to stop the movement of a group of people (giving the impression that time had stopped)  was seen in the second *[X-Men](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X2_(film))* film:

We know that he isn't stopping time, since the news report on the TV continues to play.

In *Logan* we know that his brain is starting to fail, so it appears that his seizures are causing his 'freezing ability' to happen beyond his control.

More information on his power is also covered here: [Has Charles Xavier ever exhibited the ability to freeze minds/time in the comics?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57208/has-charles-xavier-ever-exhibited-the-ability-to-freeze-minds-time-in-the-comics)

Comment: Isn't that x 2?

Comment: @cde Good spot - corrected

Comment: Ok thanks! So it paralyzes the muscles, except the heart and the lungs probably?

Comment: @MicroMachine Seems likely. I know in the comics that he can alter a persons perception of events, so my speculation is that when he did it in x-2 he was essentially 'pausing' the brain, while keeping their heart/lungs going.

Answer (score 2):

Xavier can cause all sorts of affects on the human brain. Having everybody stop moving is something he does in multiple films. The last time being the Wolverine stinger, we're Xavier, having stolen his twin brain dead brothers body and essentially coming back to life after being atomized by the Phoenix, shows up at the airport and stops time.

Keep in mind, these seizures cause a different affect. Paralysis of motor functions, but not mental functions.  **The earlier ones stopped their brains so they don't even know they were paralyzed, but here they know.** And can't breathe, so even the autonomous PNS actions are stopped. Caliban knew he was frozen, knew he couldn't breathe.